# How can I perform a fuzzy search for all words provided in a Lucene.net search

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, fuzzy-search

I am trying to teach myself Lucene.Net to implement on my site.  I understand how to do almost everything I need except for one issue.  I am trying to figure out how to allow a fuzzy search for all search terms in a search string.

So for example if I have a document with the string `The big red fox`, I am trying to get `bag fix` to match it.

The problem is, it seems like in order to perform fuzzy searches, I have to add `~` to every search term the user enters.  I am unsure of the best way to go about this.  Right now I am attempting this by

```
string queryString = "bag rad";
queryString = queryString.Replace("~", string.Empty).Replace(" ", "~ ") + "~";
```

The first replace is due to Lucene.Net throwing an exception if the search string has a `~` already, apparently it can't handle `~~` in a phrase.  This method works, but it seems like it will get messy if I start adding fuzzy weight values.

Is there a better way to default all words to allow for fuzzyness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to index your documents as bi-grams or tri-grams. Take a look at the [CJKAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/cjk/CJKAnalyzer.html) to see how they do it. You will want to download the source and look at the source.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I get the core concept of the CJKAnalyzer, but I think I need to study up on Lucene a lot more before I try and just copy the java code over to C# and write my own tokenizers and analyzers

Comment: [Here's](http://code.google.com/p/bzreader/source/browse/trunk/Snowball.NET/Extra/CJKTokenizer.cs?r=33) the equivalent Lucene.NET code.